# How to initiate function passed from parent via props from grandparent

Tags: reactjs

I've got a nest of react components (its a modal).

```
<Modal> // Grandparent
  <Footer> // Parent
    <Button label="Click Me" clickAction={
      () => {

        /* So what goes here? */

      }
    }/> //Child
  </Footer>
</Modal>
```

Modal passes all children the close modal function. This function gets passed again to all children of footer.

```
export default class Footer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }
  handleClose() {
    this.props.closeModal();
  }

  render() {

    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
      (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
        closeModal: this.handleClose
      })
    );

    return (
      <footer}>
        {childrenWithProps}
      </footer>
    );
  }
}
```

The internals of the button class look like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }

  click() {
    this.props.clickAction();
  }


  render() {

    return <a
      href='#'
      onClick={this.click}
    >
      {this.props.label}
    </a>
  }
```

What I don't want to do is bake the close method right into the button since it's supposed to only have access to it when it's a child of modal footer.

So the thing I'm trying to solve (see the first code block) is what goes in the /* So what goes here? */ area. Using 'this' just returns 'undefined' so I'm having trouble reaching my closeModal method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the problem? Looks like you've already found a solution.

Comment: See in the first block where I wrote /* So what goes here? */ . That's what I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah figured out the problem. The arrow functions didn't have 'this' bound.

```
<Button label="Click Me" clickAction={
  // Nope
  // () => {this.closeModal()}

  // Yup
  function(){this.closeModal()}
}/>
```

Comment: Nah, it just says 'this' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You might consider only passing props to components that need to use them. In other words, just explicitly pass the `closeModal` function to your button as a prop:

```
function Footer (props) {
  return (
    <footer>{props.children}</footer>
  )
}

function Button (props) {
  return (
    <a href='#' onClick={props.onClick}>{props.label}</a>
  )
}

class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this)
  }

  closeModal () {
    /* implement me */
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Footer>
          <Button label='Click Me' onClick={this.closeModal} />
        </Footer>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This way, you don't have to think about the context of the button, i.e. which props are being "invisibly" passed to it via a parent pattern like the `cloneElement` technique you've used. Some components which are children of `Footer` might not need access to `closeModal`, so there's no reason to pass it to them.

Comment: Yea I thought about this, but I didn't want to bake this stuff into the Modal. Modal, Footer and Button are 3 separate components but can be nested.

Comment: You don't have to! The modal really just needs to accept a prop for `open`, and it can conditionally render based on that. Here's a full example where the parent component (`App`) handles all the state https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KmE9UQuk0FExtF_Fn-s

Comment: ^ Edited to only mount the modal if it is open

Comment: This is close to what I'm going for. Is there a way to do this so the opening and closing modal functions are inside the modal? That's the part I'm stuck on. I'm trying to keep the component usage as minimal as possible so you just have to use <Modal> anywhere and it knows how to close itself (along with its children) without having to define this at it's parent scope.

Comment: Also, wow, webpackbin. I had no idea. Gonna use that a lot :D

Comment: Your previous pattern would allow for that, but to me that isn't ideal. For example, what if another component needs to know if the modal is open or not? If the state of the modal is constrained to the modal itself, then you can't easily determine this.